# Template bound propertyChanged event is only called once on a page containing four of the templates

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a template that I use for a button. I placed four of these buttons on a page like this:

```
<template:Button Meta="gst" Grid.Column="1" Selected="{Binding Mode[0].Selected}" Text="{Binding Mode[0].Name}" TapCommand="{Binding ModeBtnCmd }" />
<template:Button Meta="gst" Grid.Column="2" Selected="{Binding Mode[1].Selected}" Text="{Binding Mode[1].Name}" TapCommand="{Binding ModeBtnCmd }" />
<template:Button Meta="gst" Grid.Column="3" Selected="{Binding Mode[2].Selected}" Text="{Binding Mode[2].Name}" TapCommand="{Binding ModeBtnCmd }" />
<template:Button Meta="gst" Grid.Column="4" Selected="{Binding Mode[3].Selected}" Text="{Binding Mode[3].Name}" TapCommand="{Binding ModeBtnCmd }" />
```

I declare an array called Mode that I use to store some values for the Selected parameter in an array declared like this:

```
public partial class HomePageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   ParamViewModel[] _mode;
   public ParamViewModel[] Mode { get => _mode; set => SetProperty(ref _mode, value); }
```

In the OnAppearing I set the value of Selected for each element in the array:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   vm.Mode[0].Selected = false;
   vm.Mode[1].Selected = false;
   vm.Mode[2].Selected = true;
   vm.Mode[3].Selected = false;
```

However I do not see the HandleSelectedPropertyChanged called for **each** of the Buttons. If I set a debug point in the HandleSelectedPropertyChanged event,  I only see it being called once.

I expect only the 3rd button to be selected but when the code runs the buttons appear as:

> Selected Selected Selected Selected

Can someone give me advice on this. **The code works when I click on the buttons one by one** and the back-end changes the selected and then the above SetButtons is called.  But it doesn't work initially and all buttons appear as selected.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese.Templates
{
    public partial class Button : Frame
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("TapCommand", typeof(Command), typeof(Button), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, defaultValue: default(Command));
        public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandParamProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TapCommandParam), typeof(object), typeof(Button), default(object));
        public static readonly BindableProperty
            SelectedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Selected),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(Button),
            false,
            propertyChanged: HandleSelectedPropertyChanged);
        public static readonly BindableProperty
            TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(Button),
            default(string));
        public static readonly BindableProperty 
            MetaProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Meta", 
            typeof(string), 
            typeof(Button), 
            default(string),
            propertyChanged: HandleMetaPropertyChanged);
        public static readonly BindableProperty VisibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Visible), typeof(bool), typeof(Button), true);
        public string Text { get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty); set => SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        public string Meta { get => (string)GetValue(MetaProperty); set => SetValue(MetaProperty, value); }
        public Command TapCommand { get => (Command)GetValue(TapCommandProperty); set => SetValue(TapCommandProperty, value); }
        public object TapCommandParam { get => (object)GetValue(TapCommandParamProperty); set => SetValue(TapCommandParamProperty, value); }
        public bool Selected { get => (bool)GetValue(SelectedProperty); set => SetValue(SelectedProperty, value); }
        public bool Visible { get => (bool)GetValue(VisibleProperty); set => SetValue(VisibleProperty, value); }

        string b;
        string s; 
        string f;

        public Button()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HasShadow = false;
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        }

        private static void HandleMetaPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object meta)
        {
            var control = (Button)bindable;
            if (control != null) {
                control.b = ((string)meta).Substring(0, 1); // background surface
                control.s = ((string)meta).Substring(1, 1); // shape
                control.f = ((string)meta).Substring(2, 1); // font

                control.BackgroundColor = control.b == "g" ?
                    (Color)Application.Current.Resources["GridButtonBackgroundColor"] :
                    (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PageButtonBackgroundColor"];

                control.BorderColor = control.b == "g" ?
                   (Color)Application.Current.Resources["GridButtonBorderColor"] :
                   (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PageButtonBorderColor"];

                if (control.s == "s")
                {
                    control.CornerRadius = 5;
                    control.Padding = new Thickness(10, 5);
                }
                else
                {
                    control.WidthRequest = 50;
                    control.HeightRequest = 50;
                    control.CornerRadius = 25;
                    control.Padding = new Thickness(0);
                }

                Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("TextButtonsLabelRes", out object textRes);
                Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("IconButtonsLabelRes", out object iconRes);

                control.ButtonLabel.Style = (control.f == "t") ?
                    (Style)textRes :
                    (Style)iconRes;
            }
        }

        private static void HandleSelectedPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object selected)
        {

            var control = (Button)bindable;
            if (control != null)
            control.ButtonLabel.TextColor =
                ((bool)selected) ?
                       (control.b == "g" ?
                            (Color)Application.Current.Resources["GridEButtonTextColor"] :
                            (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PageEButtonTextColor"]) :
                       (control.b == "g" ?
                            (Color)Application.Current.Resources["GridButtonTextColor"] :
                            (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PageButtonTextColor"]);
        }

        private async void ChangeTheColours(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((string)this.ButtonLabel.Text.Substring(0, 1) != " ")
            {
                BackgroundColor = this.b == "g" ?
                       (Color)Application.Current.Resources["GridCButtonBackgroundColor"] :
                       (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PageCButtonBackgroundColor"];
                BorderColor = this.b == "g" ?
                   (Color)Application.Current.Resources["GridCButtonBorderColor"] :
                   (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PageCButtonBorderColor"];
                await Task.Delay(500);
                BackgroundColor = this.b == "g" ?
                       (Color)Application.Current.Resources["GridButtonBackgroundColor"] :
                       (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PageButtonBackgroundColor"];
                BorderColor = this.b == "g" ?
                   (Color)Application.Current.Resources["GridButtonBorderColor"] :
                   (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PageButtonBorderColor"];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

For reference here's the SetProperty function:

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(
        ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

}
```

Just as a reminder the code and method here is working good except for the initial set up where it does not seem to call the propertyChanged event as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value on your `SelectedProperty` is false, `OnPropertyChanged` is only fired when the current value differs from the new value. Hence only the 3rd button, whose value is being set to `true` is being fired.

You have to define your initial state of the control in its constructor. Upon any property changes the subsequent changes will be handled in the `PropertyChanged` handler

Comment: "You have to define your initial state of the control in its constructor" < can this be defined from the bound parameters and is the value I set in the bound parameters available in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, the default value of the binding properties are reflected when used inside the constructor